# "Cannot assign Add because it is a method group" error in C# when cycling through loop

Tags: c#, linq

Hello right now when ever it cycles through I want it to add the info from each site. Currently it just overwrites it

```
foreach (Site s in sites)
{

    foreach (OffSiteItemDetails d in s.ItemDetails)
    {

        model.OffReportColumns.Add new List<string>()
            {
                s.Name,
                "",
                "",
                "Average Cost",
                "",
                "",
                "Average Cost (With labour)"
            };
    }
}
```

When I do `model.OffReportColumns.Add = new List<string>()`

I receive the error **Cannot assign Add because it is a method group**

I'm thinking that I just have syntax of it wrong so what is the proper syntax?

Comment: you have choice : 1 - ``model.OffReportColumns.AddRange(new List<string>()..)`` or ``model.OffReportColumns = new List<string>()...``

Comment: What type is `OffReportColumns`?

Comment: List<string>  @JohnathanBarclay

Comment: Your example code is invalid.  The error is due to you not having bracets around the `new List` after the add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking to use `AddRange` if you want to add a list of strings to a list of strings.  Don't forget the parentheses as well.

```
model.OffReportColumns = new List<string>();  

foreach (Site s in sites)
{

    foreach (OffSiteItemDetails d in s.ItemDetails)
    {

        model.OffReportColumns.AddRange(new List<string>()
        {
            s.Name,
            "",
            "",
            "Average Cost",
            "",
            "",
            "Average Cost (With labour)"
        });
    }
}
```

Or you could set the property to a new List

```
foreach (Site s in sites)
{

    foreach (OffSiteItemDetails d in s.ItemDetails)
    {

        model.OffReportColumns = new List<string>()
        {
            s.Name,
            "",
            "",
            "Average Cost",
            "",
            "",
            "Average Cost (With labour)"
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do the addRange I get the error of "Object Reference not set to an instance of  an object" And the 2nd way you showed is how I originally had it. However with this way it will just keep overwriting the list everytime it cycles through

Comment: you need to instantiate *OffReportColumns* before first loop, like   ``model.OffReportColumns = new List<string>()`` and use ``AddRange`` method.

Comment: @chris agree with Sajid and modified my answer.  Hard to give a solid solution without seeing more of your code.  If this answer works for you, please mark it as the answer to your question.